# How to speed up the sum of presence of keys in the series of documents? - Pandas, nltk

Tags: python, string, list, pandas, nltk

I have a dataframe column with documents like

```
38909    Hotel is an old style Red Roof and has not bee...
38913    I will never ever stay at this Hotel again. I ...
38914    After being on a bus for -- hours and finally ...
38918    We were excited about our stay at the Blu Aqua...
38922    This hotel has a great location if you want to...
Name: Description, dtype: object
```

I have a bag of words like `keys = ['Hotel','old','finally']` but the actual length of `keys = 44312`

Currently Im using

```
df.apply(lambda x : sum([i in x for i in keys ]))
```

Which gives the following output based on sample keys

```
38909    2
38913    2
38914    3
38918    0
38922    1
Name: Description, dtype: int64
```

When I apply this on actual data for just 100 rows timeit gives

```
1 loop, best of 3: 5.98 s per loop
```

and I have 50000 rows. Is there a faster way of doing the same in nltk or pandas.

EDIT :
In case looking for document array

```
array([ 'Hotel is an old style Red Roof and has not been renovated up to the new standard, but the price was also not up to the level of the newer style Red Roofs. So, in overview it was an OK stay, and a safe',
   'I will never ever stay at this Hotel again. I stayed there a few weeks ago, and I had my doubts the second I checked in. The guy that checked me in, I think his name was Julio, and his name tag read F',
   "After being on a bus for -- hours and finally arriving at the Hotel Lawerence at - am, I bawled my eyes out when we got to the room. I realize it's suppose to be a boutique hotel but, there was nothin",
   "We were excited about our stay at the Blu Aqua. A new hotel in downtown Chicago. It's architecturally stunning and has generally good reviews on TripAdvisor. The look and feel of the place is great, t",
   'This hotel has a great location if you want to be right at Times Square and the theaters. It was an easy couple of blocks for us to go to theater, eat, shop, and see all of the activity day and night '], dtype=object)
```

Comment: How many elements are there in `keys` in your actual case?

Comment: I added that there are about 45000 keys

Comment: So, for the EDIT sample, the output would be : `[2, 1, 2, 0, 0]`, right? Are you looking for a case sensitive output?

Comment: Yes. and not worried much about case sensitivity case insensitive is fine too.

Comment: What's keys? Like vocabulary?

Comment: @alvas keys is a list of words. Yeah much like vocabulary.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following code is not exactly equivalent to your (slow) version, but it demonstrates the idea:

```
keyset = frozenset(keys)
df.apply(lambda x : len(keyset.intersection(x.split())))
```

Differences/limitation:

1. In your version a word is counted even if it is contained as a substring in a word in the document. For example, had your `keys` contained the word **tyl**, it would be counted due to occurrence of "style" in your first document.
2. My solution doesn't account for punctuation in the documents. For example, the word **again** in the second document comes out of `split()` with the full stop attached to it. That can be fixed by preprocessing the document (or postprocessing the result of the `split()`) with a function that removes the punctuation.

Comment: TBH I was using set. Let me try the frozenset version.

Comment: @Bharathshetty I don't think that `set` vs `frozenset` will result in much difference, if any

Comment: Forget to mention I failed in my set approach. Your approach is super fast.

Comment: Yes. Using a `set` for `keys` is pointless if you'll just iterate over the set's elements, as the code in your question does. This solution is the way to go.

Answer (score 2):

It seems you can just use [`np.char.count`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.13.0/reference/generated/numpy.core.defchararray.count.html) -

```
[np.count_nonzero(np.char.count(i, keys)) for i in arr]
```

Might be better to feed a boolean array for counting -

```
[np.count_nonzero(np.char.count(i, keys)!=0) for i in arr]
```

Comment: I think numpy is slow when it comes to strings. Though I learnt something new

Comment: @Bharathshetty Yup, that's been the case.

Answer (score 1):

If need check only if present values of list:

```
from numpy.core.defchararray import find

v = df['col'].values.astype(str)
a = (find(v[:, None], keys) >= 0).sum(axis=1)
print (a)
[2 1 1 0 0]
```

Or:

```
df = pd.concat([df['col'].str.contains(x) for x in keys], axis=1).sum(axis=1)
print (df)
38909    2
38913    1
38914    1
38918    0
38922    0
dtype: int64
```

Comment: My kernel crashed trying my method. Restarting it. Will come up with speed comparision soon.

Comment: I din't get you. keys as list of list?

Comment: No no all words are single verbs and are split by space. No phrases

Comment: I have put that in the question around 45000

Comment: Hmmm, is possible duplicates like in first row `Hotel is an old style Red Hotel and has not bee.` ?

Comment: because if need count `Hotel` twice, then set cannot be used.

Comment: no I wanted it to be only once. I wanted to find the sum of presence of a string.

Comment: I remove findall solution, because it return multiple values if present.