# keyword matching gives repeated words in pandas column?

Tags: python, pandas, text-mining

I have a pandas dataframe consists two columns as:-

```
ID           text_data                               

1         companies are mainly working on two 
          technologies that is ai and health care.
          Company need to improve on health care.

2         Current trend are mainly depends on block chain
          and IOT where IOT is
          highly used.

3         ............
.         ...........
.         ...........
.         so on.
```

Now I have a another list as `Techlist=["block chain","health care","ai","IOT"]`

I need to match list `Techlist` with `text_data` column of pandas dataframe so I've use this code:-

```
df['tech_match']=df['text_data'].apply(lambda x: [reduce(op.add, re.findall(act,x)) for act in Techlist if re.findall(act,x) <> []] )
```

so what I've got is something different as:-

```
ID         text_data                                           tech_match
1     companies are mainly working on two          [ai,healthcarehealthcare]             
      technologies that is ai and health care.
      Company need to improve on health care.

2     current trend are mainly                     [block chain,IOTIOT]
      depends on block chain and 
      IOT where IOT is highly used.

3    .................
.    ................             
.    ...............
.    so on.
```

List and text data got matched correctly but the matched list words are repeating in `tech_match` column.

What I need is:-

```
ID            text_data                             tech_match
1     companies are mainly working on two           [heatlh care,ai]
      technologies that is ai and health care.
      Company need to improve on health care.

2     Current trend are mainly depends on          [block chain,IOT]
      blockchain and IOT where IOT is
      highly used. 

3     ..................
.     ..................
.     .................
.     son on.
```

how can I delete these repeating words in `tech_match` column?

Comment: Use a [`set()`](https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/stdtypes.html?highlight=set#set)

Comment: Holy heck, that is an inefficient function you are applying. First, **do not** use `reduce(op.add, re.findall(act,x))`, you should `''.join` strings, not `+` them together, one is O(n), the other is O(n^2). Also, you call `re.findall(act,x)` **twice**, just write a full function and stop trying to fit everything into a one-liner!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `str.split` and then call `set.intersection`:

```
s = set(["blockchain", "healthcare", "ai", "IOT"])

df['matches'] = df.text_data.str.split(r'[^\w]+')\
                   .apply(lambda x: list(s.intersection(x)))
df

                                           text_data            matches
0  companies are mainly working on two technologi...   [healthcare, ai]
1  Current trend are mainly depends on blockchain...  [IOT, blockchain]
```

Thanks to [Bharath](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47120018/4909087) for the setup data.

Comment: Please check my updated list if list also having word with space in between then code doesn't able to extract it like "block chain" "health care"? I want to extract both "blockchain" as well as "block chain"

Answer (score 4):

As an alternative for regex we can use `nltk.word_tokenize` then apply set i.e

```
text_data = ["companies are mainly working on two data itegration technologies that is and healthcare. Company need to improve on healthcare.", "Current trend are mainly depends on blockchain and IOT where IOT is highly used."]

df = pd.DataFrame({'text_data':text_data})

Techlist=["blockchain","healthcare","ai","IOT"]
import nltk

df['new'] = df['text_data'].apply(lambda x :  list(set([i for i in nltk.word_tokenize(x) if i in Techlist])))
```

```
                                      text_data                new
0  companies are mainly working on two data itegr...       [healthcare]
1  Current trend are mainly depends on blockchain...  [IOT, blockchain]
```

For the faster application of the same you can see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46669144/how-to-speed-up-the-sum-of-presence-of-keys-in-the-series-of-documents-pandas)

Comment: It seems it is slow :(

Comment: Yes sir I had the speed  issue from long ago. Even you saw here . https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46669144/how-to-speed-up-the-sum-of-presence-of-keys-in-the-series-of-documents-pandas

Comment: @Bharath one more thing as when I have updated the list with elements having space in between then code not able to detect that particular word.. please check my updated "Techlist" now "blockchain" is able to detect by code but not "block chain"?

Comment: Thats a bit hard one to get.

Answer (score 3):

Use [`str.findall`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.str.findall.html) with `boundary` for look-up words. Thank you [Anton vBR](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47119965/keyword-matching-gives-repeated-words-in-pandas-column/47119991?noredirect=1#comment81190441_47119991) for simplier pattern:

```
pat = '|'.join(r"\b{}\b".format(x) for x in Techlist)
print (pat)
\bblockchain\b|\bhealthcare\b|\bai\b|\bIOT\b
```

Create new column with:

```
df['tech_match'] = df['text_data'].str.findall(pat).apply(lambda x: list(set(x)))

print (df)
                                           text_data         tech_match
0  companies are mainly working on two technologi...   [healthcare, ai]
1  Current trend are mainly depends on blockchain...  [blockchain, IOT]
```

---

You can return dicts with counts of each word with `Counter`, thanks `Anton vBR` again for suggestion:

```
from collections import Counter

df['tech_match'] = df['text_data'].str.findall(pat).apply(lambda x: Counter(x))

print(df)

    text_data                                           tech_match
0   companies are mainly working on two technologi...   {'ai': 1, 'healthcare': 2}
1   Current trend are mainly depends on blockchain...   {'blockchain': 1, 'IOT': 2}
```

**Furthermore** you could join the count series with the original frame:

```
data = (df['text_data'].str.findall(pat).apply(lambda x: Counter(x))).tolist()
df = df.join(pd.DataFrame(data)).fillna(0) # join dfs
df['Total'] =df[Techlist].sum(axis=1) # create Total column

   text_data          IOT   ai  blockchain  healthcare  Total 
0  companies are ...  0.0  2.0         0.0        2.0    4.0
1  Current trend ...  2.0  0.0         1.0        0.0    3.0
```

---

**Timings**:

```
text_data = "companies are mainly working on two technologies that is ai and healthcare. Company need to improve on healthcare. Current trend are mainly depends on blockchain and IOT where IOT is highly used.".split()

np.random.seed(75)
#20000 random rows with all words from text_data
N = 20000
df = pd.DataFrame({'text_data': [np.random.choice(text_data, size=np.random.randint(3,10)) for x in range(N)]})
df['text_data'] = df['text_data'].str.join(' ')


Techlist=["blockchain","healthcare","ai","IOT"]
s = set(["blockchain", "healthcare", "ai", "IOT"])

#cᴏʟᴅsᴘᴇᴇᴅ's solution
In [401]: %timeit df['matches'] = df.text_data.str.split(r'[^\w]+').apply(lambda x: list(s.intersection(x)))
10 loops, best of 3: 165 ms per loop

#jezrael's solution
In [402]: %timeit df['tech_match'] = df['text_data'].str.findall('|'.join([r"\b{word}\b".format(word=word) for word in Techlist])).apply(lambda x: list(set(x)))
10 loops, best of 3: 74.7 ms per loop

#Bharath's solution
In [403]: %timeit df['new'] = df['text_data'].apply(lambda x :  list(set([i for i in nltk.word_tokenize(x) if i in Techlist])))
1 loop, best of 3: 3.73 s per loop
```

Comment: For a fair comparison, you'd need to scale tech list as much as you scale df, because `findall` becomes a lot slower for many patterns. Otherwise these timings don't really mean much.

Comment: @cᴏʟᴅsᴘᴇᴇᴅ - no difference, `findall` the fastest

Comment: @AntonvBR - Thanks. I think `set`s should be faster, right?

Comment: @jezrael Please check my updated list if list also having word with space in between then code doesn't able to extract it like "block chain" "health care"? I want to extract both "blockchain" as well as "block chain"